# How can I use both 24 CPUs and 240 instances?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

There are [region quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas) for CPUs and instances:

> CPUs: 24
>   Virtual Machine (VM) Instances: 240

How can I use 240 instances when there are just 24 CPUs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [at the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/#stopping_an_instance):

> Instances that are in a TERMINATED state are not charged for
>   per-minute running virtual machine usage and do not count towards your
>   regional CPU quota

Therefore, you can have up to 240 instances but only up to 24 [running](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/#checkmachinestatus) if you use single-core instances.